# Getting jsonpath error when executing any commands in zsh

Tags: zsh

```
error: error executing jsonpath "{.contexts[?(@.name==\"\")].context.namespace}": Error executing template: <nil> is not array or slice and cannot be filtered. Printing more information for debugging the template:
    template was:
        {.contexts[?(@.name=="")].context.namespace}
    object given to jsonpath engine was:
        map[string]interface {}{"apiVersion":"v1", "clusters":interface {}(nil), "contexts":interface {}(nil), "current-context":"", "kind":"Config", "preferences":map[string]interface {}{}, "users":interface {}(nil)}
```

Comment: What's the exact command you are running? The shell may be altering an unquoted argument.

Comment: Please provide the information requested by @chepner. The same command works fine on bash?

Comment: I am getting this error while opening my terminal itself . Also when I run even a ls command or cd I am getting this error after showing the command results.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue. It started after I upgraded my kubectl to a newer version.
In my case In my zsh I have a custom prompt using POWERLEVEL_9K plugin which displays the current k8s cluster/namespace.
This prompt config in my ~/.zshrc looks like

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status root_indicator command_execution_time kubecontext background_jobs history time)
```

Remove kubecontext from there and here you go.

If you'd like to remain k8s info in your prompt, the template in the theme needs to be fixed. I was using POWERLEVEL9K and switching to POWERLEVEL10K did a trick for me.